# Content Box is a Little Off in IE9 ... How to Fix?

Tags: html, css

**Hi there**! I have a website at [www.thetotempole.ca](http://thetotempole.ca/anchorman2.html) and when viewed in IE9... My websites content box (The green wooden backgrounded box with content inside) is moved slightly over to the left making a space between the actual container and the content box... Is there anyway I can fix this without harming any of the other browsers? Thanks!

Screenshot:

[image]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>The Totem Pole News - Movies</title>
    <!-- Start WOWSlider.com HEAD section -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="engine1/style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- End WOWSlider.com HEAD section -->
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-45342007-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="A totem pole themed news website posting articles on news, music, movies, video games, and health.">
<link href="thecss2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="images/favicon.ico">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="contentbox" align="Center">
<a href="index.html"><div id="banner" align="Center">
</div></a>
<div id="navbar">
  <p><a href="index.html"><img src="images/home.png" width="65" height="54" alt="picture of a house to relate to the home page (content)" style="position: absolute; left: 23px; top: 16px; width: 57px; height: 48px;"><span style="position: absolute; left: 24px; z-index:2; top: 71px; height: 23px;">Content</span></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/eagleicon.gif" width="73" height="39" alt="An Eagle icon for the News section of the Totem Pole" style="position: absolute; left: 111px; top: 28px;"><span style="position: absolute; z-index: 2; left: 127px; top: 72px;">News</span></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/owlicon.gif" width="81" height="61" alt="An Owl icon for the Music section of the totem pole" style="position: absolute; left: 210px; top: 11px;"><span style="position: absolute; z-index:2; left: 226px; top: 73px;"><strong>Music</strong></span></a><a href="movies.html"><img src="images/wolficon.gif" width="88" height="54" alt="A Wolf icon for the Movies section of the totem pole" style="position: absolute; left: 320px; top: 15px;"><span style="position: absolute; left: 336px; top: 72px; z-index:2;"><strong>Movies</strong></span></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/hareimage.gif" width="60" height="56" alt="A Hare icon for Video Game section of the Totem Pole" style="position: absolute; left: 441px; top: 13px;"><span style="position: absolute; z-index:2; left: 428px; top: 73px;"><strong>Video Games</strong></span></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/bearicon.gif" width="91" height="57" alt="A bear icon for the Health section of The Totem Pole" style="position: absolute; left: 551px; top: 13px;"><span style="position: absolute; left: 580px; top: 72px; z-index:2;">Health</span></a></p>
</div>
<!--Nav Bar 2-->
<div id="navbar2">
<a href="#">About Us</a> <a href="#">Feedback</a> <a href="#">Subscribe</a>
</div>
<!-- Atomz HTML for Search -->
<div id="searchbar">
<form method="get" action="http://search.atomz.com/search/">
  <input id="searchbox" size="13" name="sp_q" value="Search..." onFocus="if (this.value == 'Search...') {this.value=''}">
  <input class="css_btn_class" type="submit" value="Search">
  <input type="hidden" name="sp_a" value="sp1005092e">
  <input type="hidden" name="sp_p" value="all">
<input type="hidden" name="sp_f" value="UTF-8">
</form>
</div>
    <!-- Start WOWSlider.com BODY section -->
    <div id="mywowslider">
    <div id="wowslider-container1">
    <div class="ws_images">
      <ul>
        <li><img src="images/anchor.jpg" alt="Ron Burgundy" title="Ron Burgundy" id="wows1_0"/>Played by Will Ferrell</li>
        <li><img src="images/anchor2.jpg" alt="Brian Fantana" title="Brian Fantana" id="wows1_1"/>Played by Paul Rudd</li>
        <li><img src="images/anchor3.jpg" alt="Brick Tamland" title="Brick Tamland" id="wows1_2"/>Played by Steve Carrell</li>
        <li><img src="images/anchor4.jpg" alt="Champ Kind" title="Champ Kind" id="wows1_3"/>Played by David Koechner</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<div class="ws_bullets"><div>
  <a href="#" title="Ron Burgundy"><img src="images/anchor.jpg" alt="Ron Burgundy"/>1</a>
  <a href="#" title="Brian Fantana"><img src="images/anchor2.jpg" alt="Brian Fantana"/>2</a>
  <a href="#" title="Brick Tamland"><img src="images/anchor3.jpg" alt="Brick Tamland"/>3</a>
  <a href="#" title="Champ Kind"><img src="images/anchor4.jpg" alt="Champ Kind"/>4</a>
</div>
</div>
<span class="wsl"><a href="http://wowslider.com"></a></span>
    <div class="ws_shadow"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/wowslider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/script.js"></script>
    </div>
    <!-- End WOWSlider.com BODY section -->
<!-- AddThis Smart Layers BEGIN -->
<!-- Go to http://www.addthis.com/get/smart-layers to customize -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-5279b96309e7df24"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  addthis.layers({
    'theme' : 'transparent',
    'share' : {
      'position' : 'left',
      'numPreferredServices' : 5
    }   
  });
</script>
<!-- AddThis Smart Layers END -->
<div id="sources"><p>
Source(s): <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anchorman_2:_The_Legend_Continues">wikipedia.com</a></p></div>
<div id="infocontent">
  <p align="left"><em><strong> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Anchorman 2: The Legend Continues</strong></em> is an upcoming American comedy film being released on December 20, 2013, also a sequel to the 2004 film <em>Anchorman: The Legend of Ron Burgandy</em>. On March 28, 2012, actor Will Ferrell officially announced the sequel dressed in character as Ron Burgundy on the late-night talk-show <em>Conan</em>. As with the original film, it is directed by Adam McKay, produced by Judd Apatow, stars Will Ferrell and is written by Adam McKay and Will Ferrell. Unlike the original film, which was distributed by DreamWorks Pictures, <em>The Legend Continues</em> will be distributed by Paramount Pictures.</p>
  <p align="left"><em><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong></em>The movie now has a website at <a href="www.anchormanmovie.com">www.anchormanmovie.com</a> where a countdown for the release of this film can be seen. By the looks of these images, I think we can expect big things when the movie comes out this December. Enjoy the poster photos and trailers all posted below, and don't forget to submit your vote in the poll!</p>
</div>
<div id="trailer1"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Elczv0ghqw0?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
<div id="trailer2">
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/mZ-JX-7B3uM?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div id="poll">
  <form method="post" action="http://poll.pollcode.com/763294"><table style="border: black 1px solid;" border="1" width="175" bgcolor="EEEEEE" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0"><tr><td colspan="2" height="10"><font face="Verdana" size="2" color="000000"><b>What Rating Do You Think This Will Recieve</b></font></td></tr><tr><td width="5"><input type="radio" name="answer" value="1" id="763294answer1"></td><td>&nbsp;<font face="Verdana" size="2" color="000000"><label for="763294answer1">10</label></font></td></tr><tr><td width="5"><input type="radio" name="answer" value="2" id="763294answer2"></td><td>&nbsp;<font face="Verdana" size="2" color="000000"><label for="763294answer2">9</label></font></td></tr><tr><td width="5"><input type="radio" name="answer" value="3" id="763294answer3"></td><td>&nbsp;<font face="Verdana" size="2" color="000000"><label for="763294answer3">8</label></font></td></tr><tr><td width="5"><input type="radio" name="answer" value="4" id="763294answer4"></td><td>&nbsp;<font face="Verdana" size="2" color="000000"><label for="763294answer4">7</label></font></td></tr><tr><td width="5"><input type="radio" name="answer" value="5" id="763294answer5"></td><td>&nbsp;<font face="Verdana" size="2" color="000000"><label for="763294answer5">6</label></font></td></tr><tr><td width="5"><input type="radio" name="answer" value="6" id="763294answer6"></td><td>&nbsp;<font face="Verdana" size="2" color="000000"><label for="763294answer6">5</label></font></td></tr><tr><td width="5"><input type="radio" name="answer" value="7" id="763294answer7"></td><td>&nbsp;<font face="Verdana" size="2" color="000000"><label for="763294answer7">4</label></font></td></tr><tr><td width="5"><input type="radio" name="answer" value="8" id="763294answer8"></td><td>&nbsp;<font face="Verdana" size="2" color="000000"><label for="763294answer8">3</label></font></td></tr><tr><td width="5"><input type="radio" name="answer" value="9" id="763294answer9"></td><td>&nbsp;<font face="Verdana" size="2" color="000000"><label for="763294answer9">2</label></font></td></tr><tr><td width="5"><input type="radio" name="answer" value="10" id="763294answer10"></td><td>&nbsp;<font face="Verdana" size="2" color="000000"><label for="763294answer10">1</label></font></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2" height="10"><center><input type="submit" value=" Vote ">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input title="Clicking this will send you to a new page" type="submit" name="view" value=" View "></center></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2" align="right"><font face="Verdana" height="5" size="1" color="000000"></font></td></tr></table></form></div>

<span style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 225px; width: 1000px; border-bottom: 2px black double; height: 58px;">
<h1 style="font-weight: normal; font-size:28px"><em>Anchorman 2 Arrives Soon</em></h1></span>
<div id="contentbox2"></div>
<!--Footer Div -->
<center><div id="footer"><a href="#">Sitemap</a> <a href="#">About Us</a> <a href="#">Feedback</a></div></center> <div id="disqus"><div id="disqus_thread"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
        var disqus_shortname = 'thetotempoleanchorman2'; // required: replace example with your forum shortname

        /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
        (function() {
            var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
            dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
            (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
        })();
    </script>
    <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="http://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
    <a href="http://disqus.com" class="dsq-brlink">comments powered by <span class="logo-disqus">Disqus</span></a></div>


<!-- This is the end of the contentbox --></div>
<!-- This is the end of the container div -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html { 
  background: url(images/pine.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/pine.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/pine.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
}
body { 
    margin-bottom:0px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

a {
    outline : none;
    border: none;
}

a:hover {
    color: #0FC;
}

#container {
    width: 1000px;
    height:1924px;
    position:relative;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    z-index:1;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

#facebook {
    position:fixed;
    right:100px;
    z-index:15;
}

#twitter {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:16;
    right:120px;
}
#google {
    position:fixed;
    top:7px;
    right: 135px;
}

#socialmediaplugins {
    text-align: right;
    position: fixed;
background: rgb(125,126,125); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(125,126,125,1) 0%, rgba(247,247,247,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(125,126,125,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(247,247,247,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(125,126,125,1) 0%,rgba(247,247,247,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(125,126,125,1) 0%,rgba(247,247,247,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(125,126,125,1) 0%,rgba(247,247,247,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(125,126,125,1) 0%,rgba(247,247,247,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#7d7e7d', endColorstr='#f7f7f7',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    margin: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index:14;
}

#searchbox {
    background-color:#01bff6;
    border-radius:4px;
}

#searchbox:hover {
    background-color:#76b618;
    border-radius:4px;
}

#searchbox:active {
    background-color:#01bff6;
    border-radius:4px;
}

#contentbox {
    background-color:black;
    background-image:url(images/wooden.jpg);
    width: 1000px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    height: 1924px;
 box-shadow:2px 2px 10px 10px #060606;
 -webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 10px 10px #060606;
 -moz-box-shadow:2px 2px 10px 10px #060606;

  /* For IE<9 */  
  filter:
  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#060606,direction=0,strength=5),
  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#060606,direction=45,strength=2),
  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#060606,direction=90,strength=5),
  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#060606,direction=135,strength=5),
  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#060606,direction=180,strength=10),
  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#060606,direction=225,strength=5),
  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#060606,direction=270,strength=5),
  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#060606,direction=315,strength=2);

}

#contentbox2 {
    background-image:url(images/woodenmovies.jpg);
    top:299px;
    width: 1000px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    height: 1625px;
    position: absolute;
}

#banner {
    background-image:url(images/totempolebanner.gif);
    position:absolute;
    top:25px;
    width:768px;
    height:120px;
    left:116px;
}

#navbar {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 146px;
    left: 76px;
    width: 844px;
    height: 158px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#navbar a { color:#0C6;
    font-size: 13px;

}

#navbar a:hover { color:#0F9;
    font-size: 13px;
}

#navbar2 a:hover { color:#0F9;
}

#navbar2 a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#0C6;
}
#navbar2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: 766px;
    width: 273px;
    height: 24px;
    font-size: 11px;
}

#searchbar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 23px;
    left: 885px;
    width: 118px;
    height: 69px;
}

.css_btn_class {
    font-size:9px;
    position: relative;
    top:0px;
    right:4px;
    width:90px;
    height:25px;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-weight:normal;
    -moz-border-radius:7px;
    -webkit-border-radius:7px;
    border-radius:7px;
    border:1px solid #35d914;
    padding:7px 24px;
    text-decoration:none;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(5%, #ff9d00), color-stop(100%, #ffe711) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ff9d00 5%, #ffe711 100% );
    background:-ms-linear-gradient( top, #ff9d00 5%, #ffe711 100% );
    background-color:#ff9d00;
    color:#ff0000;
    display:inline-block;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 1px #117cff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #117cff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #117cff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #117cff;
    background-image: url(images/unnamed.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:right; 
}.css_btn_class:hover {
    width:90px;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(5%, #ffe711), color-stop(100%, #ff9d00) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ffe711 5%, #ff9d00 100% );
    background:-ms-linear-gradient( top, #ffe711 5%, #ff9d00 100% );
    background-color:#ffe711;
    background-image: url(images/unnamed.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:right; 
}.css_btn_class:active {
    position:relative;
    width:90px;
    top:1px;
    background-image: url(images/unnamed.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:right; 
}
/* This css button was generated by css-button-generator.com */

img {border:none;}
#eagle {
    position:relative;
    right: 144px;
    top:299px;
}
#owl {
    top:624px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
        }

#wolf { 
    top:949px;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
        }
#hare {
    top:1274px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
        }
#bear {
    top:1599px;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
        }
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 393px;
    top: 1941px;
    width: 251px;
    color: #0F9;
}
#footer a {
    color: #0f9;
}
.atss { left: 0; }

#infocontent {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    left: 15px;
    top: 333px;
    height: 348px;
    width: 789px;
}

#mywowslider {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    left: 640px;
    top: 684px;
}

#poll {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    left: 815px;
    top: 344px;
}

#trailer1 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    left: 40px;
    top: 598px;
}

#trailer2 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    left: 40px;
    top: 948px;
}

#trailer1header {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    left: 200px;
    top: 550px;
    width: 240px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: normal;
}

#trailer2header {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    left: 200px;
    top: 898px;
    width: 241px;
    height: 51px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: normal;
}

#disqus {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    left: 0px;
    top: 1340px;
}

#sources {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    left: 394px;
    top: 1249px;
    width: 212px;
}
```

Comment: Were you able to fix it yourself? Because I don't see any difference in IE9 compared to Chrome and Firefox. If not, can you provide us with a screenshot?

Comment: added an image! still not fixed

Comment: Looks fine in IE11, btw. I have to ask, though, why are you using `position:absolute` for things that should be positioned statically?

Comment: Its working fine in IE9 over here, so I'm not sure this will fix it, but try removing the `filter` css from `#contentbox`. It looks like its increasing the size of the div.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I use it to move things around in dreamweaver easily

Comment: @KelseyNealon Ew, Dreamweaver... Real programmers don't use such software ;)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol well than, what do you use?

Comment: @KelseyNealon I use Notepad++. I used to use Notepad, and I still do use it when I'm programming on a computer that isn't mine. Actually, one time I programmed on my Nintendo DS because there was an important bug to fix and I had no computer at all!

Answer (score 1):

I've tried your site in in IE9 and it looks like it looks in Chrome. It looks fairly awful in IE8, the background and positions are all broken. So I can only suggest that you fix the X-UA-Compatible meta tag and remove the IE8 part, try:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Comment: looking on Windows 7 IE9 the tag <center> ??? that holds the footer is 1020px wide with a left:50px and is breaking your site in IE

Comment: Hmm well I deleted the center tags and still no luck.

Comment: Can't do this one at a time, You're going to have to work out which element(s) in the content are causing you issues. Use the Developer tools built into IE9 to examine the layout of each Div. Look at the size, offset, padding and margin values to see what's causing the content shunt. Comment out items one at a time until you don't get the break and then uncomment the breaking item and work through it's sub-items in the same way until you find the root cause of the issue.